# Is there any way in eclispe to link the child class to mother class by clicking

Tags: python, django, eclipse, ide

I didn't knew what was the right way to ask but i will explain here.

Suppose this is my class django in eclispe

```
class DcumentCreate(ParentCreate):
    parent_model = models.Objective
```

Now this means that i am extending class from `ParentCreate` class.

Now is there any setting in eclipse that i should be able to click on those ParentCreate text and it opens that class or document, rtaher than browsing the folder

I really don't know if thats possible or not but just asking

Comment: usually you hold ctrl and click, try it out. You might need the Aptana extension installed though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my PyDev which seems to be year old already, one can place the mouse over any identifier, and a tooltip appears; the tooltip has a clickable link to the place of definition.

However do note that if you anywhere happen to have multiple ParentCreate classes it is very hard for a Python IDE to actually know which one of these is the right one.

Also the ctrl-click mentioned by @calderonmluis works.

Comment: it says  module not in python path